# PhantomJS copy file with overwrite

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Reading from their [document](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/):

`copy(source, destination)`

Currently, the way I cope with this is to check `fs.exist('myfile')` and manual delete it prior to copy:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = 'myfile-backup.txt';

if (fs.exists(fileName)) {
    fs.remove(fileName);
}
fs.copy('myfile.txt', fileName);

phantom.exit();
```

I don't know if there is any better way to overwrite the file. Checking for existing file may have a potential problem when I can't remove the file. I will probably need to do more error handling with this approach. It seems to be a common task, so I would like to know what solution people come up with.

Comment: I don't know if there is any better way to overwrite the file. Checking for existing file may have a potential problem when I can't remove the file. I will probably need to do more error handling with this approach. It seems to be a common task, so I would like to know what solution people come up with. I will re-phrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [small extension](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/ba62deba39ca966c9422) to the `fs` module. If you try to overwrite a file with `fs.copy` it will throw an exception which you can catch to do some error handling like removing an existing file.

I also added an optional `maxTrials` argument if there is a problem that the file is created every time in between the `copy` trial and the `remove`.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.overwrite = function(source, destination, maxTrials){
    var overwritten = false;
    var trials = 0;
    maxTrials = parseInt(maxTrials)
    maxTrials = !!maxTrials ? maxTrials : null;
    while(!overwritten) {
        if (maxTrials && trials > maxTrials) {
            return -1;
        }
        try {
            this.copy(source, destination);
            overwritten = true;
        } catch(e) {
            if (fs.exists(destination)) {
                fs.remove(destination);
            } else {
                return -2;
            }
        }
        trials++;
    }
    return trials;
};
```